# Command Not Found when assigning an integer variable from another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

To illustrate my issue and questions consider two scripts.

Script1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
test=1
echo $test
```

Script2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
$(Script1.sh)
```

When I run Script1.sh from the command line directly via ./Script1.sh it produces the desired output.

1

However when I run Script2.sh which calls Script1.sh, instead I get the following error message:

Script2.sh:  line 1: 1: command not found

It thinks that the integer 1 is a command for some odd reason?

I found a cheap work around which is to set a variable from the first script and pass it to the second script as a parameter but I would like to understand why this is failing.

Also, when I changed my variables value from 1 to "some text", I would expect that my echo would print "some text" to the screen.  But when I call Script2.sh (which ultimately just calls Script1.sh) it doesn't print the echo to the screen.  Why is that, and how do I resolve it so I can see the echo output the same as if I would have called Script1.sh directly?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're getting that effect because that's what `$( )` means. It takes the output of the enclosed command, and basically treats it as part of the current command. So, `ls $(Script1.sh)` will expand to `ls 1`, which will try to list a file named "1". So what you have, `$(Script1.sh)`, expands to just `1`, which tries to run "1" as a command.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it wrong by using command substitution. Just use `source` or a subshell if you want it:

```
. ./Script1.sh
( ./Script1.sh )
```

The second one is a bit redundant since it will always run in another shell anyway, so this would make more sense instead:

```
( . ./Script1.sh )
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I believe I should be set now.